# SHGetSpecialFolderPath() Not Declared in This Scope

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am not able to compile my program SHGetSpecialFolderPath() not being declared in the scope of the program, while the correct header is being included (according to MSDN)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204(v=vs.85).aspx

Here are the headers for my project:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <direct.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
```

With error:
C:\Users\user\Documents\getAppData\main.cpp|31|error: `SHGetSpecialFolderPath' was not declared in this scope

with shlobj.h being the header with the declaration in it. 
Any ideas why the compiler is throwing the error? Here is how I am calling the function:

```
char appData[MAX_PATH];
SHGetSpecialFolderPath( NULL
                        ,appData
                        ,CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA
                        ,1 );
cout << appData << endl;
```

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Windows is your project targeting? Look for a `#define WINVER` statement.

Comment: Hmm, then it definitely should be defined. Everything works perfectly in a new, blank Win32 project. But even once you'll fix that, you'll run into another problem, though: converting `char[]` into `LPWSTR` as required by the second parameter to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MSDN page:

> The Microsoft Internet Explorer 4.0
>   Desktop Update must be installed for
>   this function to be available.
>
> With Windows 2000, this function is
>   superseded by ShGetFolderPath. You can
>   use this function on earlier systems
>   by including the redistributable DLL,
>   ShFolder.dll.

Perhaps this is your problem?

Comment: Yep, thats it! Switched to ShGetFolderPath.

Comment: Note, of course, that [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181.aspx) is *itself* deprecated. For apps targeting Windows Vista and later, you should use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188.aspx). (Perhaps eventually they'll find a name they like and stick with it?)

Comment: I agree that `SHGetFolderPath`/`SHGetFolderLocation` should be used instead. However lack of MSIE 4.0 would **not** be the cause of the compilation error. I believe the problem is with incorrect/undefined `WINVER`

Comment: @valdo: Yes, agreed. However, I think it's more likely the problem is with the definition of the `_WIN32_IE` symbol, given that the function is provided by IE 4.0. Not really enough info available in the question to be sure.